# Jquery string filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm doing a little fancy snippet of js to automatically copy the value of a textbox into a later span.

```
<input name="data[ask_admin_name]" onkeyup=
    "$("#admin_name").html($(this).val())"
type="text" id="ask_admin_name">
```

and then, later,

```
<span id="admin_name"></span>
```

What is the fastest, easiest, most jquery-est way to strip html-related tags out of this, like `<` and `>`?

I could do it using some more lines of js, but I'm wondering if there's a specific function for this task, for example, `$(this).val().strip('<>');`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method instead:

```
<input onkeyup="$('#admin_name').text(this.value)">
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Wu4N/

Comment: Is `this.value` the same as `$(this).val()` ?

Comment: It is! Awesome - that'll be faster, too.

Comment: @Erty In result yes. `value` is a native form element property. It will work faster than if you use jQuery `val()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an element from the html you want to strip and then run jQuery .text() method on that element.

```
$("<p>bla</p>").text() // bla
```